# About the orbits of the action of $\mathrm{GL}(n,A)$ on $A^n$ when $A$ is a finite dimensional commutative real algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Consider a finite-dimensional commutative associative real algebra $A$. Let $e_i$ be the canonical basis of $V:=A^n$. Define $$V^\bullet := \{p \in V: \text{the morphism }A \to Ap\text{, given by } x\mapsto xp \text{, is an isomorphism}\}.$$

> **How do I prove the following statement? Given $p \in V^\bullet$ there exists $M \in \mathrm{GL}(n,A)$ such that $Me_1 = p$. Equivalently, the action of $\mathrm{GL}(n,A)$ on $V^\bullet$ is transitive.**

What I know so far:

Since $A = A^\times \sqcup A_z$, where $A^\times$ is the set of units and $A_z$ is the set of zero divisors, and $A^\times$ is a dense open set we have $(A^\times)^n \subset V^\bullet$ as dense subset. Furthermore, it is easy to construct $M$ for $p \in (A^\times)^n$. Just take
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
p_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
p_2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
p_3 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots\\
p_n & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

The same argument works if at least one coordinate of $p$ is a unit. Maybe the result can be proved using this density.